Can class templates cause a security issue in Windows?
This is my code :
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Calculator
{
    T _Number1, _Number2;

public:

    Calculator(T num1, T num2)
    {
        _Number1 = num1;
        _Number2 = num2;
    }

    void PrintResult()
    {
        cout << _Number1 << " + " << _Number2 << " = " << Add() << endl;
        cout << _Number1 << " - " << _Number2 << " = " << Subtract() << endl;
        cout << _Number1 << " * " << _Number2 << " = " << Multiplay() << endl;
        cout << _Number1 << " / " << _Number2 << " = " << Diviade() << endl;

    }

    T Add()
    {
        return _Number1 + _Number2;
    }

    T Subtract()
    {
        return _Number1 - _Number2;
    }

    T Multiplay()
    {
        return _Number1 * _Number2;
    }

    T Diviade()
    {
        return _Number1 / _Number2;
    }

};

int main()
{
    
    Calculator <int> IntCalc(12, 20);
    Calculator <float> FloatCalc(15.2, 82.6);

    cout << "Int Calculator : \n";
    IntCalc.PrintResult();

    cout << "\n\nFloat Calculator : \n";
    FloatCalc.PrintResult();


    return 0;
}

And this is the "Threat Detected" by Bitdefender:
"Threat Detected" by Bitdefender
Another Capture
I'm trying to do a simple Template Class in C++, but I'm facing build errors and the antivirus warning me that it "Blocked a Threat"!

Your code isn't good, but it shouldn't cause AV to report a threat. Something fishy is going on, please contact your admin.

No template classes are not a virus threat on their own. I've seen false positives on my own build outputs every now and then. (It can make sense to exclude your target build folders from your scanner, also just to speed up build times)

there are not class templates at runtime anymore (it is "class template" not "template class". They are templates , not classes)
